# Container border only wraps header and nav, not entire container

Tags: css

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Joshi3s/2gMWf/1/

I'm trying to wrap the entire container in a 1px solid border... but it only wraps around the header and nav.

I feel like a float is an issue but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do differently?  Any other criticisms are also welcome.

P.S. I'm learning and trying to convert .PSD's to HTML, with tutorials that I find on the internet.  This is one that I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your #container definition:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Floated elements are removed from the normal flow of block level elements on the page, so and adding the overflow attribute makes the height of the parent include the children as if they weren't floated.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to clear your floatings. Put a div like `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`
on the end of the container div.

After it works, you can create a class named clear like that and use to clear your floatings

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

Study about floats on the tutorials and you will use that a lot.